# cakephp attach word document on email

Tags: cakephp

I'm working with CakePHP and i need to send email with attachment here is my code

```
function sendAsEmail($data) {
    App::import('Component', 'Email');
    $user = $this->Sender->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Sender.id' => $data['Message']['sender_id']),
    ));
    $Email = new EmailComponent();
    if ($this->useDbConfig == 'test') {
        $Email->delivery = 'debug';
    }

    $Email->sendAs = 'html';
    $Email->from = 'info@admin.ca';
    $Email->return = Configure::read('App.systemAdminEmail');
    $Email->bcc = array($data['Message']['recipient_text']);
    $Email->attachments = $data['Message']['attachments'];
    $Email->subject = $data['Message']['subject'];
    $content = $data['Message']['message'];
    $replyToAddress = isset($data['Message']['reply_to_address']) ? 
        (bool)$data['Message']['reply_to_address'] : false;
    if (!$replyToAddress) {
        $content .= "\n\n".__("Please do not reply to this email", true);
    } elseif (!empty($data['Message']['reply_to'])) {
        $Email->replyTo = $data['Message']['reply_to'];
    }
    if (Configure::read('App.systemAdminEmail')) {
        $Email->additionalParams = '-f'.Configure::read('App.systemAdminEmail');
    }

    $Email->send($content);
    return true;
}
```

i have my attachments on $data['Message']['attachments'] and still i cant see the attachment on email

any help?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$Email->attachments` expects array containing the paths to the files to attach. Make shure you have in `$data['Message']['attachments']` array of paths, and not only the filenames...

Comment: i do this one 

$Email>filePaths=array($html>url('/files/event_documents/',true)); // document path
$Email->attachments = $data['Message']['attachments']; //file name but still the file doesn't attach to the email

Comment: `debug($data['Message']['attachments'])` should output an array like: array('/var/www/myapp/tmp/filename1.pdf', '/var/www/myapp/tmp/filename2.pdf') - it has to be array of paths...

Comment: but i put my file on webroot/files/filename.docx

Comment: so in your case `/var/www/YOURCAKEPHPAPPLICATION/webroot/files/filename.docx`

Comment: @ grzegorz_motyl thanks and it works now i just miss the other format